# Watir .hover function does not work for firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

When using the following method in combination with firefox you'll get an error:

```
browser.element(:attribute, 'value').hover
```

Error showing:

> Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.

Installed gems

- Watir-webdriver 0.6.10
- selenium-webdriver 2.42.0
- Firefox 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the .hover method, use the fire_event method with the value 'onmouseover'

```
browser.element(:attribute, 'value').fire_event "onmouseover"
```